# My code is not working for a component, there is sme import and export warning in app.js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, jsx, mern

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import ComplaintForm from "./components/ComplaintForm";
import LoginPage from "./components/LoginPage";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import NotFound from "./components/NotFound";
import chatList from "./components/chatList.jsx";

function App() {
  
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
         <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Header />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
          <Route path="/fill_complain" element={<ComplaintForm />} />
          <Route path="/chat" element={<chatList />} />
          {/* <classList /> */}
          
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
 classList.jsx                                                                                                                enter image description here 
import React from 'react';
function chatList() {
  return (
    
<div class="flex h-screen antialiased text-gray-800">
    <div class="flex flex-row h-full w-full overflow-x-hidden">
      <div class="flex flex-col py-8 pl-6 pr-2 w-64 bg-white flex-shrink-0">
        <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-center h-12 w-full">
          <div
            class="flex items-center justify-center rounded-2xl text-indigo-700 bg-indigo-100 h-10 w-10"
          >
            <svg
              class="w-6 h-6"
              fill="none"
              stroke="currentColor"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <path
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
                stroke-width="2"
                d="M8 10h.01M12 10h.01M16 10h.01M9 16H5a2 2 0 01-2-2V6a2 2 0 012-2h14a2 2 0 012 2v8a2 2 0 01-2 2h-5l-5 5v-5z"
              ></path>
            </svg>
          </div>
          <div class="ml-2 font-bold text-2xl">QuickChat</div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="flex flex-col items-center bg-indigo-100 border border-gray-200 mt-4 w-full py-6 px-4 rounded-lg"
        >
          <div class="h-20 w-20 rounded-full border overflow-hidden">
            <img
              src="https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/2763884?s=128"
              alt="Avatar"
              class="h-full w-full"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="text-sm font-semibold mt-2">Aminos Co.</div>
          <div class="text-xs text-gray-500">Lead UI/UX Designer</div>
          <div class="flex flex-row items-center mt-3">
            <div
              class="flex flex-col justify-center h-4 w-8 bg-indigo-500 rounded-full"
            >
              <div class="h-3 w-3 bg-white rounded-full self-end mr-1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="leading-none ml-1 text-xs">Active</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col mt-8">
          <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-between text-xs">
            <span class="font-bold">Active Conversations</span>
            <span
              class="flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-300 h-4 w-4 rounded-full"
              >4</span
            >
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-col space-y-1 mt-4 -mx-2 h-48 overflow-y-auto">
            <button
              class="flex flex-row items-center hover:bg-gray-100 rounded-xl p-2"
            >
              <div
                class="flex items-center justify-center h-8 w-8 bg-indigo-200 rounded-full"
              >
                H
              </div>
              <div class="ml-2 text-sm font-semibold">Henry Boyd</div>
            </button>
            <button
              class="flex flex-row items-center hover:bg-gray-100 rounded-xl p-2"
            >
              <div
                class="flex items-center justify-center h-8 w-8 bg-gray-200 rounded-full"
              >
                M
              </div>
              <div class="ml-2 text-sm font-semibold">Marta Curtis</div>
              <div
                class="flex items-center justify-center ml-auto text-xs text-white bg-red-500 h-4 w-4 rounded leading-none"
              >
                2
              </div>
            </button>
            <button
              class="flex flex-row items-center hover:bg-gray-100 rounded-xl p-2"
            >
              <div
                class="flex items-center justify-center h-8 w-8 bg-orange-200 rounded-full"
              >
                P
              </div>
              <div class="ml-2 text-sm font-semibold">Philip Tucker</div>
            </button>
            <button
              class="flex flex-row items-center hover:bg-gray-100 rounded-xl p-2"
            >
              <div
                class="flex items-center justify-center h-8 w-8 bg-pink-200 rounded-full"
              >
                C
              </div>
              <div class="ml-2 text-sm font-semibold">Christine Reid</div>
            </button>
            <button
              class="flex flex-row items-center hover:bg-gray-100 rounded-xl p-2"
            >
              <div
                class="flex items-center justify-center h-8 w-8 bg-purple-200 rounded-full"
              >
                J
              </div>
              <div class="ml-2 text-sm font-semibold">Jerry Guzman</div>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-between text-xs mt-6">
            <span class="font-bold">Archivied</span>
            <span
              class="flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-300 h-4 w-4 rounded-full"
              >7</span
            >
          </div>
          <div class="flex flex-col space-y-1 mt-4 -mx-2">
            <button
              class="flex flex-row items-center hover:bg-gray-100 rounded-xl p-2"
            >
              <div
                class="flex items-center justify-center h-8 w-8 bg-indigo-200 rounded-full"
              >
                H
              </div>
              <div class="ml-2 text-sm font-semibold">Henry Boyd</div>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-col flex-auto h-full p-6">
        <div
          class="flex flex-col flex-auto flex-shrink-0 rounded-2xl bg-gray-100 h-full p-4"
        >
          <div class="flex flex-col h-full overflow-x-auto mb-4">
            <div class="flex flex-col h-full">
              <div class="grid grid-cols-12 gap-y-2">
                <div class="col-start-1 col-end-8 p-3 rounded-lg">
                  <div class="flex flex-row items-center">
                    <div
                      class="flex items-center justify-center h-10 w-10 rounded-full bg-indigo-500 flex-shrink-0"
                    >
                      A
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="relative ml-3 text-sm bg-white py-2 px-4 shadow rounded-xl"
                    >
                      <div>Hey How are you today?</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-start-1 col-end-8 p-3 rounded-lg">
                  <div class="flex flex-row items-center">
                    <div
                      class="flex items-center justify-center h-10 w-10 rounded-full bg-indigo-500 flex-shrink-0"
                    >
                      A
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="relative ml-3 text-sm bg-white py-2 px-4 shadow rounded-xl"
                    >
                      <div>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
                        elit. Vel ipsa commodi illum saepe numquam maxime
                        asperiores voluptate sit, minima perspiciatis.
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-start-6 col-end-13 p-3 rounded-lg">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-start flex-row-reverse">
                    <div
                      class="flex items-center justify-center h-10 w-10 rounded-full bg-indigo-500 flex-shrink-0"
                    >
                      A
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="relative mr-3 text-sm bg-indigo-100 py-2 px-4 shadow rounded-xl"
                    >
                      <div>I'm ok what about you?</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-start-6 col-end-13 p-3 rounded-lg">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-start flex-row-reverse">
                    <div
                      class="flex items-center justify-center h-10 w-10 rounded-full bg-indigo-500 flex-shrink-0"
                    >
                      A
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="relative mr-3 text-sm bg-indigo-100 py-2 px-4 shadow rounded-xl"
                    >
                      <div>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing. ?
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-start-1 col-end-8 p-3 rounded-lg">
                  <div class="flex flex-row items-center">
                    <div
                      class="flex items-center justify-center h-10 w-10 rounded-full bg-indigo-500 flex-shrink-0"
                    >
                      A
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="relative ml-3 text-sm bg-white py-2 px-4 shadow rounded-xl"
                    >
                      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet !</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-start-6 col-end-13 p-3 rounded-lg">
                  <div class="flex items-center justify-start flex-row-reverse">
                    <div
                      class="flex items-center justify-center h-10 w-10 rounded-full bg-indigo-500 flex-shrink-0"
                    >
                      A
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="relative mr-3 text-sm bg-indigo-100 py-2 px-4 shadow rounded-xl"
                    >
                      <div>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing. ?
                      </div>
                      <div
                        class="absolute text-xs bottom-0 right-0 -mb-5 mr-2 text-gray-500"
                      >
                        Seen
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-start-1 col-end-8 p-3 rounded-lg">
                  <div class="flex flex-row items-center">
                    <div
                      class="flex items-center justify-center h-10 w-10 rounded-full bg-indigo-500 flex-shrink-0"
                    >
                      A
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="relative ml-3 text-sm bg-white py-2 px-4 shadow rounded-xl"
                    >
                      <div>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                        Perspiciatis, in.
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-start-1 col-end-8 p-3 rounded-lg">
                  <div class="flex flex-row items-center">
                    <div
                      class="flex items-center justify-center h-10 w-10 rounded-full bg-indigo-500 flex-shrink-0"
                    >
                      A
                    </div>
                    <div
                      class="relative ml-3 text-sm bg-white py-2 px-4 shadow rounded-xl"
                    >
                      <div class="flex flex-row items-center">
                        <button
                          class="flex items-center justify-center bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-800 rounded-full h-8 w-10"
                        >
                          <svg
                            class="w-6 h-6 text-white"
                            fill="none"
                            stroke="currentColor"
                            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                          >
                            <path
                              stroke-linecap="round"
                              stroke-linejoin="round"
                              stroke-width="1.5"
                              d="M14.752 11.168l-3.197-2.132A1 1 0 0010 9.87v4.263a1 1 0 001.555.832l3.197-2.132a1 1 0 000-1.664z"
                            ></path>
                            <path
                              stroke-linecap="round"
                              stroke-linejoin="round"
                              stroke-width="1.5"
                              d="M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"
                            ></path>
                          </svg>
                        </button>
                        <div class="flex flex-row items-center space-x-px ml-4">
                          <div class="h-2 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-2 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-4 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-8 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-8 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-10 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-10 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-12 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-10 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-6 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-5 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-4 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-3 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-2 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-2 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-2 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-10 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-2 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-10 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-8 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-8 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-1 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-1 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-2 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-8 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-8 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-2 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-2 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-2 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-2 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                          <div class="h-4 w-1 bg-gray-500 rounded-lg"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            class="flex flex-row items-center h-16 rounded-xl bg-white w-full px-4"
          >
            <div>
              <button
                class="flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-600"
              >
                <svg
                  class="w-5 h-5"
                  fill="none"
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <path
                    stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round"
                    stroke-width="2"
                    d="M15.172 7l-6.586 6.586a2 2 0 102.828 2.828l6.414-6.586a4 4 0 00-5.656-5.656l-6.415 6.585a6 6 0 108.486 8.486L20.5 13"
                  ></path>
                </svg>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-grow ml-4">
              <div class="relative w-full">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  class="flex w-full border rounded-xl focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-300 pl-4 h-10"
                />
                <button
                  class="absolute flex items-center justify-center h-full w-12 right-0 top-0 text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-600"
                >
                  <svg
                    class="w-6 h-6"
                    fill="none"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  >
                    <path
                      stroke-linecap="round"
                      stroke-linejoin="round"
                      stroke-width="2"
                      d="M14.828 14.828a4 4 0 01-5.656 0M9 10h.01M15 10h.01M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"
                    ></path>
                  </svg>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ml-4">
              <button
                class="flex items-center justify-center bg-indigo-500 hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded-xl text-white px-4 py-1 flex-shrink-0"
              >
                <span>Send</span>
                <span class="ml-2">
                  <svg
                    class="w-4 h-4 transform rotate-45 -mt-px"
                    fill="none"
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  >
                    <path
                      stroke-linecap="round"
                      stroke-linejoin="round"
                      stroke-width="2"
                      d="M12 19l9 2-9-18-9 18 9-2zm0 0v-8"
                    ></path>
                  </svg>
                </span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   
  )
};

export default chatList;
```

All other components of my code is working properly with no errors but this part of code is not working good and I am getting output as blank. Kindly solve this.

i am getting this as an error and it is not showing in output.[Error image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHXAo.png)

I have attached image of my folder structure and also included codes of component files in mycode, so please have a look at the code and check what I am doing wrong in the code and hence reply me.

Comment: I doubt this is the cause of the linter warning, but conventionally React components are capitalised e.g. `<ChatList />`

Comment: Can you delete the `<div className="App">` component, and then move the `<Routes>` component just below the `<Router>` component?